# Some rows remains in a DataGrid when deleting multiple rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF triggered (TextChanged) function which calls two other function whose subroutine deletes rows from a DataGrid object when certain conditions are met.

I have a feeling I might be encountering race conditions on the delete of multiple rows. When I place a `MessageBox.Show("somethings');` in between the two functions, 2 rows from DataGrid are deleted as expected with the message box popping up in between delete actions.

```
deleteFunction("item1");
MessageBox.Show("something");
deleteFunction("item2");
```

However if I remove the MessageBox only the first function deletes a single row (item1)from DataGrid.

```
deleteFunction("item1");
deleteFunction("item2");
```

I have tried all sorts of ways to resolve this, Thread.Sleep(500) in between function calls, setting up a Queue to FIFO the requests, thread locking. async ... Nothing seems to work for me.

I'm not even sure it is actually a race condition issue anymore. I am starting to wonder if there is some Thread connection to the DataGrid object that the MessageBox is severing when invoked and releasing the control for another function to interact with.

Code below:

```
private void streamCode_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (configurationSectionLoaded == true)
    {
        streamCodeAlphanumeric(streamCode.Text);
        streamCodeIsChar128(streamCode.Text);
    }
    formEdited = true;
}

private bool streamCodeAlphanumeric(string value)
{
    dataValidation dv = new dataValidation();
    if (dv.isAlphanumeric(value))
    {
        streamCode.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        editStreamcode.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        editStreamcode.IsEnabled = true;
        //MessageBox.Show("scE01 Deleting");
        //q.Enqueue(new UILogDeleteQueue() { qEntryType = "scE01" });

        try
        {
            UILogRemoveRow("scE01");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        editStreamcode.IsEnabled = false;
        streamCode.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
        UILogAddRow("scE01", "Stream Code", "Non-Alphanumeric Characters Detected!");
        return false;
    }
}

private bool streamCodeIsChar128(string value)
{
    dataValidation dva = new dataValidation();
    if (dva.isChar128(value))
    {
        streamCode.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        editStreamcode.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        editStreamcode.IsEnabled = true;
        //MessageBox.Show("scE02 Deleting");

        try
        {
            UILogRemoveRow("scE02");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        editStreamcode.IsEnabled = false;
        streamCode.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
        UILogAddRow("scE02", "Stream Code", "Invalid Length Detected!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally here is the delete row code:

```
private void UILogRemoveRow(string entryCode)
{
    int rowCount;
    rowCount = UILog.Items.Count;
    if (rowCount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)UILog.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            var selectedItem = UILog.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (row != null)
            {
                UILogObject theItem = (UILogObject)row.DataContext;
                if (theItem.entryType == entryCode)
                {
                    UILog.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: included `UILogAddRow` function**

```
private void UILogAddRow(string entryCode, string entryIdentifier, string entryDetail)
{
    bool itemExists = false;
    int rowCount;
    rowCount = UILog.Items.Count;
    if (rowCount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)UILog.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (row != null)
            {
                UILogObject theItem = (UILogObject)row.DataContext;
                if (theItem.entryType == entryCode)
                {
                    itemExists = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(rowCount.ToString());
    }
    if (itemExists != true)
    {
        UILog.Items.Add(new UILogObject() { entryType = entryCode, identifier = entryIdentifier, detail = entryDetail });
    }
    UILog.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: have you checked that `DataGridRow row ` is not null, when you are deleting items without delay (`deleteFunction("item1");deleteFunction("item2");`)? It may be DataGrid virtualization issue

Comment: Yes this is tested as shown above in the `UILogRemoveRow` function, but I have not prompted if it is null.

Comment: Are the two rows both visible in the grid at the time the `TextChanged` event is raised?  Also, is there a reason you can't simply remove the row objects from the collection backing the grid's `ItemsSource`?

Comment: Yes two rows are visible when the text changes, but then when I remove the non-alphanumeric character the other item remains.

Comment: @ASh I just checked by binding a button click to `UILog.items.count` and there is still an item in the datagrid which it detectable programatically when there is only one record in the datagrid.

Comment: @MikeStrobel there is no itemsSource per se, as I understand it, I am adding the rows dynamically based on the result of user input. I added the `UILogAddRow` function above where I do `UILog.Items.Add(new UILogObject() { entryType = ...`

Comment: @mm8 based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949957/wcf-debugging-event-not-triggering-unless-messagebox-show-is-performed) SO thread, it seemed like a very similar problem, however I am not convinced that this is the issue. However I can say, every time the `MessageBox.Show()` is invoked between delete functions, both entries clear, which is the desired outcome. The delete function (shown above - `UILogRemoveRow`) Iterates through the rows, finds any rows with matching `entryType` as the value passed to the function, and deletes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of working with low-level container elements (DataGridRow), cast items to your known type, and then search and remove

```
private void UILogRemoveRow(string entryCode)
{
    var item = UILog.Items.OfType<UILogObject>()
                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.entryType == entryCode);
    if (item != null)
        UILog.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: This worked right away, I'm still teaching myself c#,  but I think I understand what is going in here. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @Majickal, you are welcome. I suggest to use the same approach when you determine `itemExists` value. also look into **MVVM** approach in wpf - it's purpose it to separate data+operations with data from low-level UI elements